# Controller spec does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im writing a simple rspec for a controller. The sign_in function does not seem to work however (although I included the rails_helper).

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe WikisController do
include Devise::TestHelpers

before do
 @user = build(:user)
 @wiki = build(:wiki)

 sign_in @user     
end

describe "#create" do
 expect(@user.votes).to be_nil
  post :create, {wiki_id: @wiki.id}
  expect {@user.wikis}.to be (1)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the user, not build it, change

```
@user = build(:user)
```

to

```
@user = create(:user)
```